# OpenSSL::SSL target is missing when find_package(OpenSSL) suceed

Tags: ssl, openssl

Unfortunately didn't find answer to this question...

I have very simple CMake code:

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

message("OpenSSL include dir: ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("OpenSSL libraries: ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")

The code is succeed, and printed correct locations for includes and libs...

But when I try to link to the OpenSSL libs this way:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PRIVATE
   OpenSSL::SSL
   OpenSSL::Crypto
   Ws2_32 crypt32 Wldap32
)
```

I have CMake errors:

Target "myTarget" links to target "OpenSSL::SSL" but the target was not
found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
an ALIAS target is missing?

Why is this happens? According to FindOpenSSL cmake docs - it is defines targets OpenSSL::SSL and OpenSSL:Crypto.

But in fact not.

Comment: I fixed the issue by linking this way:
   ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
instead of OpenSSL::SSL

But strange that OpenSSL::SSL and OpenSSL::Crypto targets cannot be linked.